# How did Lord Rayleigh find the volume fraction of argon to air?

Tags: classical-mechanics, density, molecules, thought-experiment

In order to isolate for pure nitrogen, Lord Rayleigh and his colleagues took some air and removed oxygen, carbon dioxide, and water vapour, leaving behind what he believed to be pure nitrogen.

In order to make sure it was pure nitrogen, he compared the density of his experimentally isolated nitrogen to the nitrogen prepared from chemical sources, and noticed that the density of nitrogen from chemical sources was half a percent lighter than the nitrogen he had experimentally isolated for.

The difference in densities allowed Lord Rayleigh to discover another gas which was argon.

We know the volume fraction of nitrogen ($\mathrm{N_2}$) in air is $78\%$, the molar mass of argon is $40$ and the molar mass of a single $\mathrm{N}$ atom is $14$.

What would be the volume fraction of argon in air?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon) we know that: the volume fraction of argon in air is $0.934\%$. But how do we go about calculating this?